# ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, python, postgresql

I am running postgresql 9.4 `("PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14), 64-bit" )`

when I am trying to create language in postgres SQL :

```
create language plpythonu;
```

then it gives following error :

> ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or
>   directory SQL state: 58P01

and i try this command :

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.4 postgresql-plpython-9.4
```

also try   `sudo apt-get install postgresql-plpython-9.4`
but no luck . its giving result is :

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     postgresql-plpython-9.4 : Depends: postgresql-9.4 (= 9.4.5-1.pgdg12.4+1) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output of `aptitude search plpython`  command is :

```
p   postgres-xc-plpython          - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p   postgres-xc-plpython:i386     - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

v   postgresql-plpython           -                           

v  postgresql-plpython:i386      -                                    

p    postgresql-plpython-8.2      - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-8.2:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-8.3       - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p   postgresql-plpython-8.3:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p   postgresql-plpython-8.4       - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-8.4:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.0       - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p   postgresql-plpython-9.0:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.1       - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.1:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.2       - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.2:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.3       - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.3:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.4       - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.4:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.5       - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

p  postgresql-plpython-9.5:i386  - PL/Python procedural language for Post 

v postgresql-plpython3          -                                    

v  postgresql-plpython3:i386     -                                    

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.1      - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.1:i386 - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.2      - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.2:i386 - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.3   - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.3:i386 - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.4      - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.4:i386 - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.5      - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po 

p  postgresql-plpython3-9.5:i386 - PL/Python 3 procedural language for Po
```

Comment: The installation of `postgresql-plpython-9.4` is blocked, because the package depends on `postgresql-9.4 (= 9.4.5-1.pgdg12.4+1)` and this version isn't installable in your system. Why? [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy postgresql-plpython-9.4 postgresql-9.4; sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4`. And please explain this `Red Hat 4.1.2-14` =)

Comment: x-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/q/33361867/398670

Comment: @A.B.  when I execute  select version()  command on postgres then it gives   PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14), 64-bit                                                             so i put in the question i think it will help .

Comment: @CraigRinger this same question i placed on stackoverflow

Comment: Yes, I know. I have posted links between them to stop people wasting their time asking the same followup questions, doing the same followup edits, posting the same answers, etc. If you post duplicates, please at least link between them to save everyone some time.

Comment: Ok i will take care of that next time .  thanks